# Unusual use of new in historical code. What does it mean?

Tags: c++, new-operator, legacy-code, placement-new

I am just porting some old code:

```
#define NewArrayOnHeap(TYPE, COUNT, HEAP, NEWPTR, ERROR) \
((*(NEWPTR) = new ( #TYPE "[" #COUNT "]", __alignof(TYPE), (HEAP), &hr, (ERROR)) TYPE[COUNT] ), hr)
```

It looks like the original was supposed to define their own magical `new` operator. I am curious about this usage.

#### Example usage

```
int main()
{
    void*   heap = /* Don't know how to define this */
    double* ptr;
    HRESULT hr;

    hr = NewArrayOnHeap(double, 10, heap, ptr, "Help /* Just guessing here */");
}
```

When I use `g++ -E` to get the preprocessor output, it's:

```
int main()
{
    double* ptr;
    HRESULT hr;

    hr = ((*(ptr) = new ( "double[ 10 ]", __alignof(double), (NULL), &hr, ("Help")) double[10] ), hr);
}
```

This looks slightly more like a `placement new`.

But is this now an overloaded new call (with some funky parameters, a five parameter `new` call), or are the commas here the comma operator and thus it gets reduced to `("Help")` (which wouldn't make sense).

Was `new` historically (or even now) allowed to have more than two parameters, `(size, hint)`?

Any help on decoding would be appreciated.

Comment: What compiler was it originally intended for?  What version, specifically.

Comment: Another reason to comment code, I suppose...

Comment: I'll bet, digging around somewhere, you'll find `#define new` ...

Comment: It means the person who wrote it didn't like C++ and was trying to pretend they were using some other language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The section you want to look at is §5.3.4/11-12, paraphrased here:

> The new-placement syntax is used to supply additional arguments to an allocation function. If used, overload resolution is performed on a function call created by assembling an argument list consisting of the amount of space requested (the first argument) and the expressions in the new-placement part of the new-expression (the second and succeeding arguments). The first of these arguments has type size_t and the remaining arguments have the corresponding types of the expressions in the new-placement.
>
> [Example:
> — new T results in a call of operator new(sizeof(T)),
> — new(2,f) T results in a call of operator new(sizeof(T),2,f),
> — new T[5] results in a call of operator new, and
> — new(2,f) T[5] results in a call of operator new[](sizeof(T)*5+y,2,f).]

So your macro, to be used correctly, requires that somewhere there's an `operator new` overload defined similar to:

```
void* operator new[](size_t, const char*, size_t, void*, HRESULT*, const char*);
```

Which I suspect uses the information given to it to allocate memory (potentially from a pre-allocated source) that satisfies alignment requirements, while logging this allocation and providing a custom error message if the allocation could not be made.

Personally, I find it gross. :)

---

The typical "placement new" operator you're referring to is defined in `<new>`, and is just another overload that accepts a `void*` and returns that as the allocation result.

Comment: "Personally, I find it gross. :)" -- exactly! People shouldn't monkey with `new` in perverted manner, that's what allocators are for.

Comment: I am seriously beginning to loathe that anonymous downvote feature.

Answer (score 3):

My assumption is that it is placement new, and that all 5 are arguments to the overload. In my inerpretation, one of the arguments is `&hr`, which is an error code and then is used as second argument to `operator,` to provide that as a result value.

I don't think that your usage of the macro is correct, in particular I believe that `NEWPTR` is intended to be the address of the actual pointer to initialize, that is, calling code should be:

```
hr = NewArrayOnHeap(double, 10, heap, &ptr, "Help");
```

which would make the expansion:

```
hr = ((*(&ptr) = new ( "double[ 10 ]", __alignof(double), (NULL), &hr, ("Help")) double[10] ), hr);
```

Without the extra `&`, the left and right hand sides of the inner assignment would not match in type: `*(ptr)` is a `double, while the result of placement new would be a`double*`.